# How can you call an executable and capture the results, yet see the executable's output on the console concurrently?

Tags: powershell

I have a PS script which will run various unit tests.  This displays the output on the screen in a readable fashion

```
$strTests = @(
"test1.dll",
"test2.dll"
)

foreach($test in $strTests)
{
    packages\xunit.runner.console.2.0.0\tools\xunit.console $test
}
```

However I want to modify this script so that if a test fails, it will not continue running the other tests.  I tried:

```
    $result = packages\xunit.runner.console.2.0.0\tools\xunit.console $test
```

Yet that prevents output going to the screen.  I've tried using Write-Host to display the contents, yet it does so in a fashion that is not as pretty as the previous version.  Plus, it just dumps the output at the end of the run instead of concurrently.

I also want to examine the results of the run and break from the loop if it failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the cmdlet `tee-object` which allows you to specify a path for our pipeline data to be output to, or a variable name to which your pipeline data will be saved. So your command would then look something like this:

```
packages\xunit.runner.console.2.0.0\tools\xunit.console $test | Tee-Object -Variable Results
```

Your output would then go to the screen as usual and also be stored in the `$Results` variable.

Comment: this particular runner is setting a variable called  `ExitCode` with the status.  Is there a way for Tee-Object to put that into `Results`

Comment: Setting a variable where, internally or within the PowerShell session that is calling it? Does it output this at all?